# Output not looking good with fontenc package?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I am writing my thesis and what I have observed that by turning off the fontenc package, the font color of the generated pdf is full black (like MS Word). But, when I turned on this package, the font color becomes slightly less black. Furthermore, the alphabets seems more stretched. I am not sure whether this problem is really caused by this package or not. But, I have gradually turned off all the packages that I am using and it turns out that this weird behaviour is caused by fontenc package. Can someone help me why is that so? I like the output without using fontenc package but without using it, I am losing '<' and '>' signs in my work.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openrights,hidelinks]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Losses Management in Low Voltage Active Distribution Networks}
In countries around the world, power sectors are undergoing significant change, with the
desire to achieve sustainable, affordable and reliable electricity. Progress in both supply- and demand-side technologies, as well as increased digitalization and automation of end uses, is influencing how the power system is planned and operated. Responding to this change requires
innovative approaches across the entire power system, spanning both institutional reforms and
technical adaptations. In view of this, idea has attained significant attention across the globe to ensure the reliable and secure operation of power system.\par 
PST is an active process of creating policy, market and regulatory environments, as
well as establishing operational and planning practices, that accelerate investment, innovation
and the use of smart, efficient, resilient and environmentally sound technology options in order to facilitate and manage requisite changes in the power sector. The interactions of technology, the physical electricity infrastructure, and market, policy and regulatory frameworks formulate the key components of this process. Being highly context specific process, the solutions from one jurisdiction cannot simply be replicated in another; however, common themes are also emerging which allow to implement a number of transferable principles across several regions and countries. \par 
In this context, this chapter examines recent trends from the perspective of PST, with a particular focus on the current structure and pathways for transforming the power system, and evolution of local (medium- and low-voltage) grids. This is followed by a comprehensive discussion on the optimal operation of  in the context of power losses assessment, which ultimately sets the foundation of the thesis work.
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Try loading the Latin Modern fonts (padkage `lmodern`) or `cm-super`..

Comment: Check at the end of the log-file if fonts ending with ".pk" are mentioned. If yes install the cm-super package. Or add \usepackage{lmodern}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you know why miktex doesn’t install cm-super by defat?

Comment: @egreg it's large. Nowadays it would be probably not really a problem to install it anyway but at the time the basic set was created it mattered. Do you know if cm-super is in the texlive basic set?